# PHP reduce duplicity connection on database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am using 3 different functions that connect on my MySQL
1th one - Check if there is any result in database for string
2th one - Display some values based on searched string 
3th one - Insert some info about search to logs

So in general First 2 seartch same table and make duplicity , and 3th one connect on same database as well just different table. I really start thinking that its not the way my script should work. Because tables are pretty big and it takea time for script to search it. So if i make duplicity it take just 2x longer what is pointless, can somebody give me some advises how can i edit it to make it faster or avoid this without security issues?

In general i create 2x connection on datbase:

data.php

```
 public function fetchByVinEvidenceDetail($con) {
     $success = false;
     try{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM evidence_calculations WHERE vin = :vin LIMIT 5";
        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindValue( "vin", $this->vin, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->execute();
        echo $this->vin;
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<br>#4";
                echo "<br>".$row['street'];
                echo "<br>".$row['city'];
                echo "<br>".$row['claim_number'];
                echo "<br>".$row['company'];
                echo "<br>".$row['country'];
                echo "<br>".$row['other'];
                echo "<br>".$row['parts'];
                echo "<br>".$row['labor'];
                echo "<br>".$row['calculation_start'];
                echo "<br> -------------------------------- <br>";
            }
            }catch(PDOExeption $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
            echo $con->errorInfo();
            }

         return $success; 
     }                   

     public function ExistVinEvidence() {
     $success = false;
     try{
        $con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS ); 
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM evidence_calculations WHERE vin = :vin LIMIT 30";
        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindValue( "vin", $this->vin, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->execute();
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();
        if ($count>0){
            echo 'For VIN:<b>'.$this->vin.'</b> we found '.$count.' rows in our far history database.</a> <br>';
        }
        else
        {
             echo 'We are sorry but we didnt find any data for VIN <b> '.$this->vin.' in far history database</b> <br>';
        }
        }catch(PDOExeption $e){
         echo $e->getMessage();
         echo $con->errorInfo();
        }
 }

 public function searchLog() {
    $correct = false;
        try {
            $date = new DateTime();
            $con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS );
            $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $sql = "INSERT INTO search_log(vin, date, user, ip, search_directory) VALUES(:vin, :date, :user, :ip, :search_directory)";

            $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bindValue( "vin", $this->vin, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( "date", $date->getTimestamp(), PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( "user", $this->getUsername(), PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( "ip", $this->getUserIP(), PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( "search_directory", "1", PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->execute();
            return "Logged";
        }catch( PDOException $e ) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
 }
```

sql.php (which i include_once to data.php)

```
  $con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS ); 
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

index.php

```
                    $data = new Data;
                    $data->storeFormValues( $_POST );
                    $data->fetchByVinEvidence();
                    $data->ExistVinEvidence();
```

and it throw error UNDEFINED $con

Comment: It indeed doesn't make sense to re-create the connection each time you need to access the db, why are you doing it?

Comment: Because i am pretty bad in PHP OOP and its my first try with PDO, thats why i ask for help :)

Answer (score 1):

Open one time the connection to the database, and pass the `$con` parameter to your functions:

```
$con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS );
$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

searchLog($con);
fetchByVinEvidenceDetail($con);
ExistVinEvidence($con);
```

And `searchLog`:

```
public function searchLog($con) {
    $correct = false;
    try {
        $date = new DateTime();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO search_log(vin, date, user, ip, search_directory) VALUES(:vin, :date, :user, :ip, :search_directory)";

        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        ...
```

Comment: Is it secure that i will not close it?

Comment: In term of security, their is no risk. However, you should call `closeCursor` on every of your `$stmt` to free resources when you will not use it anymore. And when you don't need your connection anymore (until the end of the script execution), you can set `$con` at `null` to free the connection.

Comment: you are right in it then with number of lines in code it can help to write code faster, but is this going to help script to run faster?

Comment: Each time you connect to the database, you have an non-negligible overhead (opening connection, establishment, etc). So yes, your script will run faster, and if you close cursors and connection, will be more memory efficient.

Comment: Thanks than, i think i understand logic , but it just throw me error that $con is not defined

Comment: You do not give enough information. Update your first post with your current solution or open another question if you think it is not related to the original question anymore.

Comment: You did not pass the `$con` argument to `fetchByVinEvidenceDetail` as I mentioned in my response. `$data->fetchByVinEvidence($con);`

Comment: yea i can try it like that and it work, but like that i have to innclude require_once('sql.php'); in each files i will work with

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the Singleton pattern to return a single instance of your PDO object throughout your application.

see : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Link to PHP implementation of singleton pattern:

http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html